# 1 px bordered UIBezierPath(roundedRect:byRoundingCorners:)

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

How to get a clean 1 px border for a UIBezierPath with different rounded corners?

In the below example, I have use 3 corners. Code is inside a `UIView`:

```
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.frame = bounds
borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 24, height: 24)).cgPath
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
borderLayer.lineWidth = 1
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

The result has width issues in angles:

[image]

Comment: I looks like maybe the layer is being clipped to the bounds, only showing half of the stroke along the edges.

Comment: I tested it in iOS 10 and nothing wrong. https://imgur.com/a/J7RB7EI

Comment: @QuocNguyen OK, maybe caused by a superview clipping. It was a UITableViewCell. JonJ solution to inset the path solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inset by 1 pixel, or set `clipsToBounds = false` in your `UIView`.

```
let insetBounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: 1.0, dy: 1.0)
borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: insetBounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 24, height: 24)).cgPath
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather inset the rounded rectangle path than the frame of the shape layer?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: `clipsToBounds = false` and `masksToBounds = false` didn't solve anything by the way (maybe due to some superview restrictions), so the key here was to have an inset. Thank you.

Comment: `bounds.insetBy(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5)` works even better.

Comment: Your insets will of course depend on your line width. 50% of it for best result.